# Different ways or efficient ways of inserting records from JTable to Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-design, jtable

I'm working on a project where I used several JTables to accept and display data. I'm now at a point where I need to insert records to 3 related tables.

**tuition**

```
id PK
gradelevel_id 
schoolyear_id
```

**fees**

```
id PK
title
amount
description
feetype_id
```

**tuition_fee**

```
id PK
tuition_id
fees_id
```

So I thought I'd create a stored procedure and put all insert statements in a transaction.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `createTuition`(aFeeTitle VARCHAR(100),aFeeAmount DECIMAL, aFeeDescription TEXT, aFeeTypeId INT, aGradeLevelId INT, aSchoolYearId INT)

BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK; RESIGNAL;
    END;
    DECLARE tuition_idVariable INT;
    DECLARE fees_idVariable INT;

    START TRANSACTION;

    -- INSERT statement 1

    INSERT INTO tuition(gradelevel_id,schoolyear_id)
    VALUES(aGradeLevelId, aSchoolYearId);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO tuition_idVariable;

    -- INSERT statement 2    

    -- this insert on `fees` I'm not sure if I can put within the transaction -- together with the insert on tuition table because I will need to do an -- iterated call on this procedure to get the records on JTable
    INSERT INTO fees(title,amount,description,feetype_id)
    VALUES(aFeeTitle,aFeeAmount,aFeeDescription,aFeeTypeId);

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO fees_idVariable;

    -- INSERT statement 3
    INSERT INTO tuition_fee(tuition_id,fees_id)
    VALUES(tuition_idVariable,fees_idVariable);

    COMMIT;

END
```

So if **every 1 tuition has MANY fees**, I'll need to do the following in in a transaction that ill put inside the stored procedure.

```
START TRANSACTION;
```

Step 1: Insert 1 record to `tuition` table

Step 1.1: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO tuition_idVariable`

Step 2: Insert MANY fees from a `JTable` to `fees` table

Step 2.1: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO fees_idVariable`

Step 3: `INSERT INTO tuition_fee(tuition_id, fees_id) VALUES(tuition_idVariable, fees_idVariable);`

On step 2, I have to iterate through each row of the `JTable` containing the fees which made me think that maybe there's a possible way to pass `JTable` bulk records as parameter to the stored procedure.

**Question 1:** Is that possible or do I still need to create a for loop like this?

```
for(int i=0; i<Jtable.getRowCount(); i++){
    String value = (String) getValueAt(i,columnNumber);
    classname.createTuition(arguments);
}
```

**Question 2:** Also, if there's no possible way to insert multiple rows (on step 2) to fees without iterated call on `creatTuition()` method, is it best to create two stored procedures?

**Question 3:** When I work with `JTables` I got used with iterated calls on stored procedures just like what's shown in my `for` loop to store records to database. Is it a good practice? Are there better and more efficient ways?

**Question 4:** How do you work with `JTables` when inserting all it's records to a `MANY` table in the database?

**Question 5:** Is my table design bad? Any suggestions?

Here's the GUI I created.

[image]

Sorry if description is lengthy. I'd sure appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***"Question 5:"*** SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk! It works best when there is one clear, specific question per thread.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Stored Procedure.  Instead do the calls, including any looping, in PHP/Java/VB/etc code.

You can construct (but not in a SP), a multi-row INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tuition_fee(tuition_id, fees_id)
      VALUES
      (tuition_idVariable, $fee1),
      (tuition_idVariable, $fee2),
      (tuition_idVariable, $fee3)
      ;
```